# Associating arbitrary properties with cells in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I’m fairly new to pandas.  I want to know if there’s a way to associate my own arbitrary key/value pairs with a given cell.

For example, maybe row 5 of column ‘customerCount’ contains the int value 563.  I want to use the pandas functions normally for computing sums, averages, etc.  However, I also want to remember that this particular cell also has my own properties such as **verified=True** or **flavor=‘salty’** or whatever.

One approach would be to make additional columns for those values.  That would work if you just have a property or two on one column, but it would result in an explosion of columns if you have many properties, and you want to mark them on many columns.

I’ve spent a while researching it, and it looks like I could accomplish this by subclassing pd.Series.  However, it looks like there would be a considerable amount of deep hacking involved.  For example, if a column’s underlying data would normally be an ndarray of dtype ‘int’, I could internally store my own list of objects in my subclass, but hack **getattribute**() so that my_series.dtype yields ‘int’.  The intent in doing that would be that pandas still treats the series as having dtype ‘int’, without knowing or caring what’s going on under the covers.  However, it looks like I might have to override a bunch of things in my pd.Series subclass to make pandas behave normally.

Is there some easier way to accomplish this?  I don’t necessarily need a detailed answer; I’m looking for a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: have you explored the option of creating custom objects by subclassing your current types (like int) and then simply adding those attributes to the custom object. you won't need to redefine most of the dunder functions that will determine its behaviour under grouping, comparing and summing, while being able to add new attributes

Comment: P.S. Ultimately, my purpose is to read and write from Google Sheets using the python API. I need to have a temporary local mirror of the data, and building a solution around Pandas seems like a reasonable basic approach.  I want to keep track of cell attributes such as whether I downloaded the cell or created it locally, so that that I can send only the new or modified data back to the cloud via the API.  Being able to set and get arbitrary attributes on Pandas cells seems like a convenient basis for building a solution, but I’m open for other ideas.

Comment: This all depends on the structure of the data, but depending on the situation I would either stack the dataframe so you have columns (row_id, column_id, cell_content, verified, flavor, etc.) or keep separate Dataframes (one for cell_content, one for "verified", etc.). Having subclasses of your current types could also be elegant, as suggested by @YatiRaj, or just use dictionaries (which would make things a bit messier when processing your data with pandas).